# c++ elevating privileges on an .exe using OpenProcess()

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have been reading some of the books by Hoglund and I thought I would have a 'go' at his 'simple debugger'...

Anyway, I have been trying to use the line

```
hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS | PROCESS_VM_OPERATION, 0, aPID);
```

Every time I use it on a running process hProcess is being returned as NULL, why is this - the target I was using was an instance of notepad.exe.

I can terminate a process no problem using:

```
hProcess = OpenProcess( PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION |
           PROCESS_VM_READ | PROCESS_TERMINATE, FALSE, aPID );
```

I am wondering how to elevate privileges, and why it doesn't work.

Thanks, R.

Comment: Please add some more context - what OS are you running on, what is GetLastError() after the failing call, etc.

Comment: I am running on windows XP pro service pack 3.  The returned message is access denied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is given in MSDN:

> Windows Server 2003 and Windows
>   XP/2000:  The size of the
>   PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS flag increased on
>   Windows Server 2008 and Windows Vista.
>   If an application compiled for Windows
>   Server 2008 and Windows Vista is run
>   on Windows Server 2003 or Windows
>   XP/2000, the PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS flag
>   is too large and the function
>   specifying this flag fails with
>   ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED. To avoid this
>   problem, specify the minimum set of
>   access rights required for the
>   operation. If PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS must
>   be used, set _WIN32_WINNT to the
>   minimum operating system targeted by
>   your application (for example, #define
>   _WIN32_WINNT _WIN32_WINNT_WINXP). For more information, see Using the
>   Windows Headers.

What OS are you targeting, and what value is being used for PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS?  If it's an OS before Vista, and the value you are passing is 0xFFFF, this could be the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Vista or Windows 7? If so, you need to embed a [UAC manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx) file in your binary. Set `requestedExecutionLevel` to `requireAdministrator` in that manifest. This should make UAC to prompt for admin password and then try to elevate privileges of your application.